# Why is a method with the same name as the class being called automatically?

Tags: php, oop, object

EDIT: Title edited to make it more useful. Originally I had no idea that it was the use of a shared word that was causing the problem.

This is very basic but rather mysterious.

I have two classes:

```
class Hello
{
        public function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
```

and

```
class World
{
    public function world()
    {
        echo " World";
    }
}
```

called by

```
include_once 'classes/Hello.php';
include_once 'classes/world.php';

$hi= new Hello;    
$wd= new World;`
```

Result `Hello World`

I originally accidentally had `hello` for the name of the class `World`'s method. 
Result `Hello` i.e. no `World`.

**Question 1**

Why are the methods firing? I have instantiated two objects but have not requested that the method “fire”. I thought I would have to do something like:

```
$hi->hello();
```

to get an output.

**Question 2**

I am even more mystified that I only get Hello if both functions are called hello.

Surely

```
$hi= new Hello;
$wd= new World;
```

instantiates two completely separate objects. So how does the actual NAME of a method affect anything?

I have a long way to go but this really confused me.

Comment: FYI: To get a quick overview of the site see: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both methods get called, when you create a new instance of this class, because the methods have the same name as the class itself and so they are the [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of this class:

```
class Hello
{
        public function hello()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
```

```
class World
{
    public function world()
    {
        echo " World";
    }
}
```

So when you took an instance from both classes, both constructors got called.

Now when you renamed both methods to `hello` only 1 method was counted as constructor and the other one was a normal method in the other class. That's why you only saw `Hello` as output.

---

**But don't use the name of the class as constructor! [It will be deprecated in PHP 7.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php#migration70.deprecated.php4-constructors) Use `__construct()`.**

Comment: This is a knowledgeable answer. I was scratching my head thinking that he has left out some code but it does make sense. Well cited too.

Comment: odd that its not even case sensitive.

Comment: @Dagon Class names are case-insensitive: `$o = new sTdClAsS;` , but you should use the name as it is declared (See the note in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: Rizier123 Fantastic. I was not deliberately making a constructor. I did not realize that was what I was doing. 10/10 helpful. Thanks. @Dragon I was testing things out.

Comment: @axiac if you are talking PHP.net I am not sure how many hours it would have taken for me to discover that naming a method the same as a class=__constructor. I have never seen that ANYWHERE.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php. It's explained in the first paragraph after Example #1.

Comment: @axiac LOL but I did not KNOW it was a constructor thang so basically I would have had to read the whole of php.net to discover that the answer was on that page - if you see what I mean. Now I can see that it was a method calling itself. And still am surprised that it works as a simple constructor and not a recursive nightmare. At the time I had no idea what was going on so RTFM does not really apply but asking helpful people on SO does. Anyhoo thanks for taking a look.